# Reiniciar linux desde batch en windows

Tags: linux, windows, batch

Tengo varias terminales con Debian instalado y necesitan ser reiniciadas diariamente. Quiero saber si existe la posibilidad de que solo ejecutando un batch desde un windows, pueda reiniciar todas las vías automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN:

**Ruta de putty.exe** -ssh **usuario@IP** -pw **Contraseña** -m **ruta de archivo de texto con comando linux**